# Windows 10 upgrade stuck at "Getting Setup Files"

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to install Windows 10 on my PC running Windows 7 Home Premium. The PC is a Dell XPS L502X with a Core i5 2450M , 6GB of RAM, Nvidia GT540M GPU. So I had started the upgrade in Windows Update. It started , but for the past 2 hours it's been stuck at "Getting Setup files".My $Windows~BT is only 230KB and there is no Windows 10 related files in my C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.

One thing to be noted is that before, the $Windows~BT folder was full of the Windows 10 related files(before) and my update log lists many "failed" updates to Windows 10. Why is this happening.? I download and install updates manually. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just download the Windows 10 .ISO, mount the .ISO, and upgrade to Windows 10.  You obviously are having problems connecting to Microsoft.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Do what exactly?  Once you have the .ISO, put it on a flash drive or burn it to a DVD, then run the installer

Comment: Could I just use the "Windows10Upgrade.exe" that I got from MS's website when I clicked upgrade now?

Comment: You could but you indicated in your question that method isn't working

Comment: I was talikng abpout the windows update method.(not the upgrade assistant)

Comment: Download the ISO you should use that instead

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Disconnect the Internet connection and try again.

**Long answer:** One of the things that Windows 10 might do during Setup is downloading from the Internet. While I have not conducted a full research as exactly how many files of what size each is downloaded, I know that it happens and that the download consists of certain updates. If you have a full Windows Setup image, these files are not mandatory (although they *will be* downloaded by the now aggressive Windows Update after the Setup.) If you have problem with the Getting Setup files stage, you might as well circumvent it by disconnecting the Internet connection.

Is it possible that the problem is something else? It is always a possibility but you gave me a very good cue when you said 'my update log lists many "failed" updates to Windows 10' which suggests the connectivity issue deserves being explored.

**Addendum:** I see that in the comment section, you have inquired as to how to download a full Windows 10 image. Home users can do so via https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/windows10. (Enterprise users must visit [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx).)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/559151)

Comment: @Burgi The solution to resolving the problem of Windows 10 Setup getting stuck at "Getting Setup Files" stage is disconnecting the Internet connection and running the setup again. So, yes, that is the answer to the question.

Comment: @FleetCommand Can you expand your answer a bit?  Perhaps address whether the OP take any steps to confirm this is truly an Internet connectivity problem?

Comment: @Twisty: I believe you are right. But the best confirmation of the issue being his Internet connection is to do the setup without it. It is certainly less complicated than `ping` and `tracert` and `NetStat` and definitely less time-taking.